# JSONObject when element doesn't exist

Tags: java, json, struts2

I have a struts action receiving following JSON:

```
{             
"commandId":"tC",       
"id":"123", 
"def":""
}
```

Following code works just fine:

```
JSONObject command = null;
String commandId = null;
String deviceId = null;
try {
  command = new JSONObject(json);
  commandId = command.getString("commandId");
}
```

Since *"def"* can be empty, non declared or can contain another array of elements I tried doing this:

```
JSONObject def = command.getJSONObject("def");
```

in order to get this JSON object defined in the element *def*

This only works if *def* isn't empty like in this example:

```
{             
    "commandId":"tC",       
    "id":"123", 
    "def":{"1":"aaa", "2":"bbb"}
}
```

When *def* is empty or not defined my program stops working on the line `JSONObject def = command.getJSONObject("def");`  and noticed that it doesn't continue the execution?!

If I put `JSONObject def = command.getJSONObject("def");`  try / catch block I get _JSONObject["def"] is not a JSONObject _ exception, but execution doesn't continue

How does `JSONObject.getJsonObject(String)` behave?

I would expect it to return an empty JSONObject and continue the execution.

What I want is to check if there is anything defined in *def* and then in a if, else decide what to do in my program according to the value found there... I can't find a way to make my program work if a client's json comes with *def* empty or not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion is to define "def" either be defined as null or {}:
"def":null or "def":{} to align with its usage agreement

quotes is really just used to indicate the value is a string. following the standard might save you and others from confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Likely it is because it is trying to get a Object and finding a string. In your JSON (if you control it), for an empty object I would do `{}`. This should allow Java to think it is retrieving an object.

Answer (score 1):

If `def` is intended to be an object is it not suppose to look like this when empty?

```
{             
"commandId":"tC",       
"id":"123", 
"def":{}
}
```

I think having `"def":""` will cause the value to be attempted to be parsed as a string value and not an object value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone. I had to solve the same problem. In my case the web service was returning empty JSON objects if it couldn't find the requested record.

Note: the data names have been changed to protect the innocent...
Note 2: this example uses javax.json

```
import javax.json.*;

JsonObject _jObj = _myRootObj.getJsonObject("someDataNode");

// at this point in execution _jObj could equal {"DataReturn":""}       
// or {"DataReturn":"<some valid data>"}
// we want to test the existence of DataReturn before trying to 
// use it

JsonValue jv = _jObj.getOrDefault("DataReturn", null);
String js = jv.toString(); 

// cover all the bases. test the value
if (js == null || js.isEmpty() || js.compareTo("\"\"") == 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Error: DataReturn object null. Cannot proceed.");
}

// the object exists, so it's ok to get it
JsonObject jObjDate = _jObj.getJsonObject("DataReturn");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `org.json.JSONObject` you can use `.isNull(String key)` to do this, something like:

```
if (command.isNull("def") {
    // Handle 'def' not being there
} else {
    JSONObject def = command.getJSONObject("def");
}
```